# Generating an indented string for a single line of text

Tags: c#, string, indentation

What is the best way to generate an indented line from space characters. I mean something similar to this:

```
    string indent = String.Join("    ", new String[indentlevel]);
    s.Write(indent + "My line of text");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can create your indention with this:

```
var indent = new string(' ', indentLevel * IndentSize);
```

`IndentSize` would be a constant with value 4 or 8.

Comment: I knew there was a simple way I was missing somewhere.  So easy to forget that String has a constructor, just like any other class.

Answer (score 11):

I would probably do something like this to add `Indent`.

```
public static string Indent(int count)
{
    return "".PadLeft(count);
}
```

To use it you can do the following:

```
Indent(4) + "My Random Text"
```

In your application you could simply do:

```
s.Write(Indent(indentLevel));
```

or

```
s.Write("".PadLeft(indentLevel));
```

Answer (score 5):

It comes in the box!

Use [`System.CodeDom.Compiler.IndentedTextWriter`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.indentedtextwriter).

Comment: I was after a more generic solution, but that's handy to know about, too.

Comment: This is generic :) Just supply any `TextWriter`, eg a `StringWriter`, or `Console.Out`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to indent every line of a string you can use this extention.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Indent(this string value, int size)
    {
        var strArray = value.Split('\n');
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in strArray)
            sb.Append(new string(' ', size)).Append(s);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
MyString.Indent(4);
```

Comment: when you do that by this way, you lose every new line. It should replace `sb.Append(new string(' ', size)).Append(s)` with `sb.AppendLine(new string(' ', size) + s)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic string extension method (it's performance and memory optimal). You can keep it inside a central 'core' project reference by your main application project(s), then whenever you want to get the indented version of any string, it's just:

```
myString.Indent(n)
```

(where 'n' is the indent level)

```
private const byte _indentSize = 4;

public static string Indent(this string originalString, int indentLevel)
{
    StringBuilder indentedString = new StringBuilder();
    indentedString.Append("".PadLeft(indentLevel * _indentSize));
    indentedString.Append(originalString);
    return indentedString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way:

```
int indentLevel = 4;
string myText = "This string will become indented";

string res = String.Format("{0," + indentLevel + "}{1}", String.Empty, myText);
```

Comment: Compiler will not recognize the separated brackets.

Comment: @SINGULARITY these brackets are located inside the string constant. Here is no problem for compiler

Comment: You're right. My pre-complier was complaining about unclosed brackets. However it did compile and run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for \r\n and \n separators.

```
   public static string Indent(this string value, string indent) {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var line in value.GetLines()) {
            builder.Append( indent ).Append( line );
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(this string value) {
        var start = 0;
        while (start < value.Length) {
            var end = value.IndexOf( '\n', start );
            if (end != -1) {
                yield return value.Substring( start, (end - start + 1) );
                start = end + 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (start < value.Length) yield return value.Substring( start );
    }
```